# CSS : How to do the reverse of line wrapper

Tags: html, css, flexbox, display

After some search, i don't find how to do the reverse of this,
I'll give a height, and the second div is under the first and the third div is on the right.

https://jsfiddle.net/qq3n52vg/

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 30px;
}

.left {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">1</div>
  <div class="left">2</div>
  <div class="left">3</div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: I cannot exactly understand what is your goal, could you explain a little more detailed what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `flexbox` that *wraps* in the *column* `flex-direction` - see demo below:

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex; /* Define a flexbox*/
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* Allow wrapping*/
  flex-direction: column; /*Column direction*/
  align-items: flex-start; /* Override default stretching*/
  align-content: flex-start; /* aligning wrapping lines */
}

 .left {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">1</div>
  <div class="left">2</div>
  <div class="left">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, it's what i Want. Big Thnks !

Answer (score 0):

More to *kukkuz* answer. For further reading about [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

**flex-direction**

[image]

This establishes the main-axis, thus defining the direction flex items are placed in the flex container. Flexbox is (aside from optional wrapping) a single-direction layout concept. Think of flex items as primarily laying out either in horizontal rows or vertical columns.

```
.container {
  flex-direction: row | row-reverse | column | column-reverse;
}
```

- `row` (default): left to right in `ltr`; right to left in `rtl`
- `row-reverse`: right to left in `ltr`; left to right in `rtl`
- `column`: same as `row` but top to bottom
- `column-reverse`: same as `row-reverse` but bottom to top